# How can I fix this problem of button in kivy?

Tags: kivy, kivy-language, kivymd

it's been for 2 days i was trying to fix my problem. I explain, I want to create an app, that contains splashscreen, and screens. And i don't understand how to create a button that bring the user to the privacy policy. I explain. When the app run, the splash screen is loading for 5 seconds and after, load the home page, till now there is no problem. But in this home page, i want to create a button that bring me to the privacy policy and for 2 days I didn't manage to. If someone could help me to suceed, it would be very nice. Have a nice day guys !

App.py

```
from os import access
from turtle import onclick
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen 
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.core.text import LabelBase 
from kivy.uix.button import Button 
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.scrollview import ScrollView

LabelBase.register(name="OpenSans",fn_regular="OpenSans-Bold.ttf")

Window.size = (360,800)

class SplashScreenApp(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        self.title = "ReviewinApp"
        global sm 
        sm = ScreenManager()
        sm.add_widget(Builder.load_file("splash.kv"))
        sm.add_widget(Builder.load_file("accueil.kv"))
        return sm
    def on_start(self):
        Clock.schedule_once(self.accueil, 10)
        
    def accueil(*args):
        sm.current = "accueil" 


        
if __name__=="__main__":
    SplashScreenApp().run()
```

accueil.kv

```
########################################################################
## MAIN SCREEN
########################################################################
MDScreen:
    name: "accueil"
    MDFloatLayout:
        md_bg_color: 41/255, 34/255, 34/255, 1
        MDLabel:
            text: "Welcome ! "
            pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.97}
            theme_text_color: 'Custom'
            text_color: 1,1,1,1
            font_size: "24sp"
            font_name: "OpenSans"
        MDLabel:
            text: "Before starting reviewing our suggestions,You need to read and accept our "
            pos_hint: {'center_x':0.5,'center_y':0.86}
            theme_text_color: 'Custom'
            text_color: 1,1,1,1
            font_size: "20sp"
            font_name: "OpenSans"
        Button:
            text: "privacy policy."
            font_size: "20sp"
            font_name: "OpenSans"
            pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.825}
            halign: 'center'
            theme_text_color: 'Custom'
            text_color: 1,1,1,1
            color: 62/255, 216/255, 133/255, 1
            size_hint: (0.4, 0.02)
            background_color: 41/255, 34/255, 34/255, 1
            background_normal: ''
            on_release: root.current = 'condition'
```

splash.kv

```
MDScreen:
    name: "splash"
    on_enter: self.ids.progress.start()
    MDFloatLayout:
        md_bg_color: 41/255, 34/255, 34/255, 1
        Image:
            source: "reviewin2.png"
            size_hint: 0.9, 0.9
            pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5,'center_y': 0.5}
        MDLabel:
            pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.3}
            halign: 'center'
            theme_text_color: 'Custom'
            text_color: 1,1,1,1
            font_size: "35sp"
        BoxLayout:
            pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.3}
            padding: "10dp"

            size_hint_x:0.7

            MDProgressBar:
                id: progress
                orientation: "horizontal" 
                type: "indeterminate"
                running_duration: 1
                catching_duration: 1
```

condition.kv

```
MDScreen:
    name: "condition"
    MDFloatLayout:
        md_bg_color: 41/255, 34/255, 34/255, 1
        MDLabel:
            text: "Privacy Policy ! "
            pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.95}
            theme_text_color: 'Custom'
            halign: 'center'
            text_color: 1,1,1,1
            font_size: "24sp"
            font_name: "OpenSans"
        MDLabel:
            text: "We are proud to see you here, to see you here, it means that you pay particular attention to our application and therefore to our working methods. "
            pos_hint: {'center_x':0.5,'center_y':0.86}
            theme_text_color: 'Custom'
            text_color: 1,1,1,1
            font_size: "20sp"
            font_name: "OpenSans"
        Button:
            text: "privacy policy."
            font_size: "20sp"
            font_name: "OpenSans"
            pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.825}
            halign: 'center'
            theme_text_color: 'Custom'
            text_color: 1,1,1,1
            color: 62/255, 216/255, 133/255, 1
            size_hint: (0.4, 0.02)
            background_color: 41/255, 34/255, 34/255, 1
            background_normal: ''
            on_release: root.current = "accueil"
```

Comment: It does not appear that you are loading `condition.kv`. Have you posted all the code?

Comment: @JohnAnderson I wanted to load condition.kv when i click to privacy policy button. And yes, I posted all the code. And thank you a lot for having answered, because i didn't think that I would get an answer. Have a great deay.

Comment: @JohnAnderson Thank you so much my brother, i just successed to do it !